# Need to put bootstrap menu icon on the right hand side

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am following following bootstrap menu item on my web site. I need put my menu icon on the right corner of the page. How can I change the codes?

```
#menu {
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Candara, "Bitstream Vera Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  /* just for this demo */
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}
#menu:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 95px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/oCBxz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `#toggle` css like this,

```
#toggle {
  margin: 30px 10px 0px auto; // changed line
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: really I need push menu items to right side according to new menu positions

Comment: Give the same margin values to #menu block. @Lion

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the hamburger icon being in the top right of the website. You can add `float:right` to the `.navbar-toggle` class to achieve this.